# How to reference to a local variable inside reactjs/JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my function:

```
  import styles from '../common.css'

  class A extends Component {

  ...

    renderBtn(expanded) {
      let btnStyle = expanded ? 'icon-circle-up' : 'icon-circle-down'
      return (
          <button className={`$styles.icon $btnStyle`}> Hi</button>

      );
    }

  }
```

Somehow the HTML comes out like this:

```
 <button class='_dqwdqweqwefvasdasdas $btnStyle'> Hi</button>
```

`$btnStyle` above is not resolved to the value stored in the variable `btnStyle`.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ES6 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) use `${}` to interpolate JavaScript, so I've no idea how the first one appears to be working for you!

```
`${styles.icon} ${btnStyle}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I dont know what `$style` does here, but this is how you use a variable as a `className`.

```
<button className={'somestring '+ btnStyle+ ' '+anyOtherVariable}> Hi</button>
```

Comment: `$styles` is from the `import styles ...` line above. I need to keep this